# Get JTextField edited from ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays

I have an ArrayList of JTextFields generated on runtime that are populated by a selected row in a JTable. I want to allow the user to edit the values inside of the JTextFields to later change the database and also update the JTable but I am having trouble finding out which JTextField was edited.

```
for(int i = 0; i < detailTextFields.size(); i++) {

        detailTextFields.get(i).getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                something(e);                 
            }

            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                something(e);
            }

            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                something(e);

            }
            public void something(DocumentEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);

            }
        });

    }
```

I currently have this working by hard coding the DocumentListener for each JTextField but the number of JTextFields could vary depending on which tab is selected so I can no longer use this:

```
JTextField pid = detailTextFields.get(0);
JTextField sid = detailTextFields.get(1);

    pid.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            something(e);                 
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            something(e);
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            something(e);

        }
        public void something(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    });

    sid.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            something(e);                 
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            something(e);
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            something(e);

        }
        public void something(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    });
```

How can I retrieve which JTextField was edited or should I go a different route to obtain this info?

Comment: As in, you just want to know which `JTextField`s have been edited so you don't end up needlessly updating your database for every field? If I'm understanding you're just looking to avoid unneeded trips to the database, because some of the information will still be the same as before?

Comment: @mypetlion correct, there is no need to update every coulmn in the database nor JTable if some values remain the same.